# Django Haystack/Solr: Show Solr field that is added in the prepare method of SearchIndex

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a `SearchIndex` subclass and I have defined a prepare method for itd.

In said prepare method, I add two entries to the `prepared_data` dictionary, this entries have lists as values. Later, when I get a `SearchResult`, I try to access these added entries' lists with the `get_additional_data()` method of `SearchResult`.

The problem is that I don't get lists back, I only get one item.

How can I get the whole list back?

Comment: I meant, the entire list

Answer (score 0):

Check your solr schema xml file.

The field you added must be a multivalued field in schema

```
<field name="entry" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

A multivalued field is useful when there are more than one value present for the field. An easy example would be tags, there can be multiple tags that need to be indexed.